# html: show localized page content without opening new page or leaving current page

Tags: javascript, html, localization

### Goal

I'm working on a localized help doc page suite, the entry page has a nav-bar at the top. Each localized page is a standalone html file, and their content will appear below the nav-bar one at a time.

### Code

The entry page looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <title>My App: Help</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="help.js" type="module"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- 
===============
Nav
===============
-->
    <nav class="grouping">
        <!-- wrap with flexbox to extend navbar to logo -->
        <div class="nav__flex">
            <ul class="nav__menu">
                <li class="nav__target pad">
                    <a></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__target"><a class="nav__link" href="home.html" onclick="ActivateSingleTab(this)">Guests</a></li>
                <li class="nav__target"><a class="nav__link" href="account.html" onclick="ActivateSingleTab(this)">Log</a></li>
                <li class="nav__target"><a class="nav__link active" href="#" onclick="ActivateSingleTab(this)">Help</a></li>
                <li class="nav__target"><a class="nav__link" href="action.html" onclick="ActivateSingleTab(this)">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav__about">
                <li class="nav__target">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="about.html">
                        <img class="nav__logo" src="images/btn-about.png" role="button" onclick="ActivateSingleTab(this)">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--
==================
Mainframe: content
==================
-->
    <!-- placeholder to push mainframe down below navbar-->
    <div class="pad-frametop"></div>
    <div class="mainframe">
        <a href="./help_en.html">English</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class=status-bar>
        0 Guest online
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Problem

My design thus excludes the use of hyperlinks, e.g., `<a href="help_en.html">` in the above source code, which would redirect and the navbar disappears.

### Attempt

The only solutions I could think of

- hacking the entry page by inserting language-specific DOM tree from localized files
- hacking the localized files by prepending the nav-bar

Both approaches would introduce code duplication.

### Question

What would be an elegant solution to embedding external html file content into a "frame" page?

Comment: Why don't you use an iframe?

Comment: @WaisKamal indeed! Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your page using an iFrame:

`<iframe src="help_en.html" title="heplsite"></iframe>`

or Objects:

`<object data="help_en.html" type="text/html"></object>`

or use embed tag:

`<embed src="help_en.html" type="text/html"/>`